# C# dynamic tree with many parameters, how to do it?

Tags: c#, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fill a tree with more than one parameter (points and types) and at the end, show which "branch" has the max of points and in every branch, show how many equal tupe I have.

The tree will be something like this:

```
FATHER (Points:200|Type:2)
|_CHILD01 (P:120|Type:3)
|  |_CHILD4 (P:300|T:3)
|  |   |_CHILD8 (P:220|T:3)
|  |   |_CHILD9 (P:65|T:1)
|  |_CHILD5 (P:15|T:9)
|_CHILD2 (P:10|T:1)
|_CHILD3 (P:80|T:2)
   |_CHILD6 (P:25|T:2)
   |  |_CHILD10 (P:110|T:7)
   |  |_CHILD11 (P:195|T:3)
   |_CHILD7 (P:50|T:7)
```

and what I am trying to get is:

```
NUMBER OF POINTS PER BRANCH:
Branch01 -> FATHER (200), CHILD01 (120), CHILD04 (300), CHILD08 (220) -> TotalPoints: 840
Branch02 -> FATHER (200), CHILD01 (120), CHILD04 (300), CHILD09 (65) -> TotalPoints: 685
Branch03 -> FATHER (200), CHILD01 (120), CHILD05 (15) -> TotalPoints: 335
Branch04 -> FATHER (200), CHILD02 (10) -> TotalPoints: 210
Branch05 -> FATHER (200), CHILD03 (80), CHILD06 (25), CHILD10 (110) -> TotalPoints: 415
Branch06 -> FATHER (200), CHILD03 (80), CHILD06 (25), CHILD11 (195) -> TotalPoints: 500
Branch07 -> FATHER (200), CHILD03 (80), CHILD07 (50) -> TotalPoints: 330
```

and

```
COUNT THE NUMBER OF TYPES in WHICH BRANCH:
TypePerBranch01:
- Type1:0
- Type2:1
- Type3:2
- Type4:1
- Type5:0
- Type6:0
- Type7:0
- Type8:0
- Type9:0
TypePerBranch02:
- Type1:1
- Type2:1
- Type3:1
- Type4:1
- Type5:0
- Type6:0
- Type7:0
- Type8:0
- Type9:0
TypePerBranch03:
- Type1:0
- Type2:1
- Type3:1
- Type4:0
- Type5:0
- Type6:0
- Type7:0
- Type8:0
- Type9:1
TypePerBranch04:
- Type1:1
- Type2:1
- Type3:0
- Type4:0
- Type5:0
- Type6:0
- Type7:0
- Type8:0
- Type9:0
TypePerBranch05:
- Type1:0
- Type2:3
- Type3:0
- Type4:0
- Type5:0
- Type6:0
- Type7:1
- Type8:0
- Type9:0
TypePerBranch06:
- Type1:0
- Type2:3
- Type3:1
- Type4:0
- Type5:0
- Type6:0
- Type7:0
- Type8:0
- Type9:0
TypePerBranch07:
- Type1:0
- Type2:2
- Type3:0
- Type4:0
- Type5:0
- Type6:0
- Type7:1
- Type8:0
- Type9:0
```

I have done some code but its not working.
Here´s the function:

```
    //
    // FUNÇÃO ResizeArray
    public T[,] ResizeArray<T>(T[,] original, int xSize, int ySize)
    {
        var newArray = new T[xSize, ySize];
        var xMin = Math.Min(xSize, original.GetLength(0));
        var yMin = Math.Min(ySize, original.GetLength(1));
        for (var x = 0; x < xMin; x++)
            for (var y = 0; y < yMin; y++)
                newArray[x, y] = original[x, y];
        return newArray;
    }


    //
    // FUNÇÃO TreeBranchPath
    int[] TotalPontosRamo = new int[1];
    int[,] FolhaInfoPontos = new int[1, 1];
    int[,] FolhaInfoPatamar = new int[1, 1];
    int CountRamos = 0;

    private void TreeBranchPath(int idusr, int usrpnts, int usrpata, int nivelnum, int ramonum)
    {
        FolhaInfoPontos[nivelnum, ramonum] = usrpnts;
        FolhaInfoPatamar[nivelnum, ramonum] = usrpata;

        var AfilhadosList = (from af in db.NRV_USERS
                             where af.idpatrocinador == idusr
                             select af).ToList();


        /*Se for NULL não tem descendentes */
        if (AfilhadosList != null)
        {
            int CountNumFilhos = AfilhadosList.Count();
            int CountFilhos = 0;
            nivelnum = nivelnum + 1;

            FolhaInfoPontos = ResizeArray(FolhaInfoPontos, nivelnum, ramonum + CountNumFilhos);
            FolhaInfoPatamar = ResizeArray(FolhaInfoPatamar, nivelnum, ramonum + CountNumFilhos);

            foreach (var descid in AfilhadosList)
            {
                CountFilhos = CountFilhos + 1;

                /* Inicio - Quantos Pontos o User tem */
                var UserPoints = (from pnt in db.NRV_USERPONTOS
                                  where pnt.iduser == descid.id_user && pnt.usrpntact == true
                                  select pnt).FirstOrDefault();

                int TotalUserPoints = UserPoints.pontosgrupo + UserPoints.pontosproprios;
                /* Fim - Quantos Pontos o User tem */

                TotalPontosRamo[CountRamos] = TotalPontosRamo[CountRamos] + TotalUserPoints;


                /* Inicio - Em que Patamar o User está */
                var AuxUserPatamar = (from cp in db.NRV_USERPATAMAR
                                      where cp.iduser == idusr
                                      select cp.idpatamax).FirstOrDefault();
                /* Fim - Em que Patamar o User está */


                Array.Resize(ref TotalPontosRamo, CountRamos + 1);

                TreeBranchPath(descid.id_user, TotalUserPoints, AuxUserPatamar, nivelnum, CountFilhos);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you cannot get answer because you question is not clear. For example what is -Type4 if it is absent in original structure?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot:

<pre>
FATHER (Points:200|Type:2)
|_CHILD01 (P:120|Type:3)
|  |_CHILD4 (P:300|T:3)
|  |   |_CHILD8 (P:220|T:3)
|  |   |_CHILD9 (P:65|T:1)
|  |_CHILD5 (P:15|T:9)
|_CHILD2 (P:10|T:1)
|_CHILD3 (P:80|T:2)
   |_CHILD6 (P:25|T:2)
   |  |_CHILD10 (P:110|T:7)
   |  |_CHILD11 (P:195|T:3)
   |_CHILD7 (P:50|T:7)

</pre>

Comment: @RicardoSousa -- I have two suggestions. First I think you should be more specific (very specific) about what is 'not working' with your current code.  Second I think you should take the information in your comment above (with the `<pre> tags and tree data) and include this in your question -- it is too difficult to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I indented the results based on the level of the Node.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node father = new Node()
            {
                name = "FATHER", points = 200, type = 2, children = new List<Node>(){
                    new Node() { 
                        name = "CHILD01", points = 120, type = 3, children = new List<Node>(){
                            new Node(){ 
                                name = "CHILD04", points = 300, type = 3, children = new List<Node>(){
                                       new Node(){ name = "CHILD08", points = 220, type = 3, children = null},
                                       new Node(){ name = "CHILD09", points = 65, type = 1, children = null}
                                }
                            },
                            new Node(){ name = "CHILD05", points = 15, type = 9, children = null}
                        }
                    },
                    new Node() { name = "CHILD02", points = 10, type = 1, children = null},
                    new Node(){ 
                        name = "CHILD03", points = 80, type = 2, children = new List<Node>(){
                            new Node(){
                                name = "CHILD06", points = 25, type = 2, children = new List<Node>(){
                                    new Node(){ name = "CHILD10", points = 110, type = 7, children = null},
                                    new Node(){ name = "CHILD11", points = 195, type = 3, children = null}
                                }
                            },
                            new Node(){ name = "CHILD07", points = 50, type = 7, children = null}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            Count results = father.GetTotals(0);

            foreach (Count result in Node.results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Name = {1}, Points = {2}, Types = {3}",
                    string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("    ", result.level)),
                    result.name,
                    result.points,
                    string.Join(",", result.types.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Key.ToString() + ":" + x.Value.ToString()).ToArray())
                    );
            }

        }
    }

    public class Count
    {
        public string name;
        public int level { get; set; }
        public int points { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, int> types { get; set; }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int points { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public List<Node> children { get; set; }
        public static List<Count> results = new List<Count>();

        public Count GetTotals(int level)
        {
            Count result = new Count();
            result.name = name;
            result.level = level;
            result.points = points;
            result.types = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            result.types.Add(type, 1);

            if (children != null)
            {

                for (int childCount = children.Count - 1; childCount >= 0; childCount--)
                {
                    Node child = children[childCount];
                    Count childResutls = child.GetTotals(level + 1);
                    result.points += childResutls.points;
                    foreach (int key in childResutls.types.Keys)
                    {
                        if (result.types.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            result.types[key] += childResutls.types[key];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result.types.Add(key, childResutls.types[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Node.results.Insert(0, result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}


​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different answer with the nodes in the same order as the input

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node father = new Node()
            {
                name = "FATHER", points = 200, type = 2, children = new List<Node>(){
                    new Node() { 
                        name = "CHILD01", points = 120, type = 3, children = new List<Node>(){
                            new Node(){ 
                                name = "CHILD04", points = 300, type = 3, children = new List<Node>(){
                                       new Node(){ name = "CHILD08", points = 220, type = 3, children = null},
                                       new Node(){ name = "CHILD09", points = 65, type = 1, children = null}
                                }
                            },
                            new Node(){ name = "CHILD05", points = 15, type = 9, children = null}
                        }
                    },
                    new Node() { name = "CHILD02", points = 10, type = 1, children = null},
                    new Node(){ 
                        name = "CHILD03", points = 80, type = 2, children = new List<Node>(){
                            new Node(){
                                name = "CHILD06", points = 25, type = 2, children = new List<Node>(){
                                    new Node(){ name = "CHILD10", points = 110, type = 7, children = null},
                                    new Node(){ name = "CHILD11", points = 195, type = 3, children = null}
                                }
                            },
                            new Node(){ name = "CHILD07", points = 50, type = 7, children = null}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            Count results = father.GetTotals();

            foreach (Count result in Node.results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Points = {1}, Types = {2}",
                    result.name,
                    result.points,
                    string.Join(",", result.types.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Key.ToString() + ":" + x.Value.ToString()).ToArray())
                    );
            }

        }
    }

    public class Count
    {
        public string name;
        public int points { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, int> types { get; set; }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int points { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public List<Node> children { get; set; }
        public static List<Count> results = new List<Count>();

        public Count GetTotals()
        {
            Count result = new Count();
            result.name = name;
            result.points = points;
            result.types = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            result.types.Add(type, 1);

            if (children != null)
            {

                for (int childCount = children.Count - 1; childCount >= 0; childCount--)
                {
                    Node child = children[childCount];
                    Count childResutls = child.GetTotals();
                    result.points += childResutls.points;
                    foreach (int key in childResutls.types.Keys)
                    {
                        if (result.types.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            result.types[key] += childResutls.types[key];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result.types.Add(key, childResutls.types[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Node.results.Insert(0, result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}


​
```